# What does "national side" mean?

Tags: meaning

In the sentence:

> He made his debut for the **national side** on 5 June 2011. <sup>[(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Gradel)</sup>

does "national side" mean "national team"?

Comment: Hi spohreis. Can I draw your attention to our [English Language Learners site](http://ell.stackexchange.org) which might be a better fit for questions like this. The 'national side' is the team of the nation.

Comment: @DJClayworth. Thanks for your help! I did not know it. I will ask there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the poster has expressed the intention to repost it on another Stack Exchange site (ELL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in this sentence "national side" means the same thing as "national team", or the sports team that is the representative of the whole nation rather than a school, private club, or other organization.